# Spinner transparent dialog background

Tags: android, xml

Ive currently got a spinner thats set to show up as a dialog box, it holds a list of items which use a custom textview to change the color and alignment.
I want to change the background of the dialog box to something transparent, currently its set to white.

Code below:
Textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#07000000"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My spinner: 
Ive set the spinners layout height and width to 0 as im using a button to make it appear:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinPlaceType"
    android:prompt="@string/spinTitle"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
     />
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinPlaceType"
    android:prompt="@string/spinTitle"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>
```

Comment: Yup that was the first thing i tried and it still shows up as white.

Comment: I have ran into such a problem recently where using a custom layout for the spinner resulted in some funny behavior where the data was invisible like it was below some other layout.

Comment: Hmm.. Im happy to leave it as it  is but i thiink it would look a lot nicer if that background of the spinner was transparent, Ive currently got it showing up on my google maps scren and it would be nice to be able to see the map through the spinner

Comment: I might look into what really is going on behind the scenes of a Spinner

Comment: Would that not require looking into the default android spinner class?

Comment: That is right; because I am sure I had that problem where using a customer layout for the individual spinner items made my spinner items invisible